# npm Err Exit handler never called

Tags: node.js, create-react-app, termux

$ npx create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in /data/data/com.termux/files/home/my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! Exit handler never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/cli/issues

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.npm/_logs/2021-10-11T17_09_35_089Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from /data/data/com.termux/files/home
Done.

Comment: With [this error being very generic and not likely the same issue as others with the same error message have](https://github.com/npm/cli/wiki/%22cb()-never-called%3F-Exit-handler-never-called%3F-I'm-having-the-same-problem!%22), it is probably the best to follow the instructions the error itself gave you: Report it to npm if not already reported. (Additionally, it would be helpful to see the complete log...) - In particular, it seems [this is closest to your issue](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3801)... - Termux is a very constrained environment, such huge packages may not work there.

Answer (score 9):

Simply downgrade your npm version to npm6 by running this command in node-

```
npm install -g npm@6
```

This will solve your issue because I have this same issue and downgrading my npm version solved it.

Answer (score 4):

Remove `package-lock.json` and then run: `npm i`, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem  `npm install --no-package-lock`  solved it for me.

If it doesn't work try to delete the package-lock.json and then  `npm install`

Comment: not solved in my case

Answer (score 0):

This error message is usually caused by a problem with the `npm` cache. You can try clearing the cache by running the following command in your terminal:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

If that doesn’t work, you can try deleting the `node_modules` folder and then running npm install again.